# zypper: How to list different available versions of a package?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

I want to get a list of all available versions of a package, the same list that you can see in Yast, but using zypper.

OpenSuse 13.1, zypper 1.9.16

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use `search -s`.  For example, `sudo zypper search -s fortune` might give this output:

```
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name    | Type       | Version      | Arch   | Repository                    
--+---------+------------+--------------+--------+-------------------------------
i | fortune | package    | 1.99.1-6.1.4 | x86_64 | 13.1-OpenSUSE-InstallOss      
i | fortune | package    | 1.99.1-6.1.4 | x86_64 | Tumbleweed-OpenSUSE-InstallOss
v | fortune | package    | 1.99.1-4.1.2 | x86_64 | 12.3-OpenSUSE-Oss             
v | fortune | package    | 1.99.1-6.1.4 | i586   | 13.1-OpenSUSE-InstallOss      
v | fortune | package    | 1.99.1-6.1.4 | i586   | Tumbleweed-OpenSUSE-InstallOss
v | fortune | package    | 1.99.1-4.1.2 | i586   | 12.3-OpenSUSE-Oss             
  | fortune | srcpackage | 1.99.1-6.1.4 | noarch | 13.1-OpenSUSE-SourceOss       
  | fortune | srcpackage | 1.99.1-6.1.4 | noarch | Tumbleweed-OpenSUSE-SourceOss 
  | fortune | srcpackage | 1.99.1-4.1.2 | noarch | 12.3-OpenSUSE-SourceOss
```

Comment: Since I just had to look it up: The **S** in the header of the first column stands for "Status". The values are: 
**i** -> Installed. 
**v** -> Another version installed.
Blank space -> Neither

Comment: ... and **i+** means package installed by user request

Answer (score -1):

If you use this trying to search for a package with a very common name you will have problems in the log output.

Let's say you want to downgrade Visual Studio code.

1. Get the repository alias, this case `code` which is also the package name
2. `zypper search -r code -s code
   Loading repository data...
   Reading installed packages...

S  | Name             | Type    | Version               | Arch   | Repository
---+------------------+---------+-----------------------+--------+-------------------
i+ | code             | package | 1.83.1-1696982959.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.83.0-1696350893.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.82.3-1696245089.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.82.2-1694671900.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.82.1-1694163779.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.82.0-1694039344.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.81.1-1691620770.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.81.0-1690980963.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.80.2-1690491680.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.80.1-1689183644.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.80.0-1688479104.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.79.2-1686734266.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.79.1-1686587726.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.79.0-1686149197.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.78.2-1683731087.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.78.1-1683194632.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.78.0-1683145689.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.50.0-1602051243.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.49.3-1601661990.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.49.2-1600965486.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.49.1-1600299354.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
v  | code             | package | 1.39.1-1570750844.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
| code-exploration | package | 1.84.0-1696907734.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
| code-exploration | package | 1.82.0-1693249536.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
| code-exploration | package | 1.82.0-1691382892.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
| code-exploration | package | 1.82.0-1691163578.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
| code-exploration | package | 1.82.0-1690973412.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
| code-exploration | package | 1.82.0-1690815369.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
| code-exploration | package | 1.81.0-1690458479.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
| code-exploration | package | 1.81.0-1690360464.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
| code-exploration | package | 1.81.0-1690275138.el7 | x86_64 | Visual Studio Code
`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).